# Kendo UI Grid Excel export issues

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the (relatively new) built-in Excel and PDF export features in Kendo UI grid, which seem pretty straightforward.  The PDF downloads with all of the data, but the Excel file just has the column headers with no data.

Just trying for the most basic implementation of this at the moment; in the grid init block I have:

```
$("#accountsContactsGrid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
    excel: {
        fileName: "DonorsGridExport.xlsx",
        filterable: true
    },
    pdf: {
        fileName: "DonorsGridExport.pdf"
    },

    dataSource: { <snip rest of datasource code...> }
});
```

The grid shows fine in the browser as well as the PDF.  It's just the Excel that is the exception, with no data showing.

I also tried pulling the buttons outside of the toolbar and using the saveAsExcel and saveAsPDF functions, and I get the same result (PDF works, Excel has no data).

Any ideas why the data would go missing just for the Excel export?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. When I export a small number of rows to Excel it works, but it stops working with a large result set.

Comment: Strange - mine doesn't work even with minimal results ( < 10).